# Change background image on reload

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to change the src of an image element on reload. I came up with this code, but it is not working for me:

```
var images = ['hero-1.jpg', 'hero-2.jpg', 'hero-3.jpg', 'hero-4.jpg', 'hero-5.jpg', 'hero-6.jpg'];
$('#hero figure img[src="images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '"]').appendTo('#hero img');
```

HTML

```
<section id="hero">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/hero-1.jpg" alt="Hero">
    </figure><!-- End figure -->
</section><!-- End section#hero -->
```

Images are placed inside the image map directly in the root.

Comment: Are all 6 images actually in the markup?

Comment: The HTML code has some mistakes. Could you fix them?

Comment: No. I have used this example: http://briancray.com/posts/simple-image-randomizer-jquery/  @Mattball

Comment: Well, that's the problem. The code selects elements which don't exist in the DOM. Note the difference in step 2 between your code and the original example.

Comment: Aha, so I should set the images in the DOM or can I select them with another way via js?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small AngularJS-app that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3276/

It contains a controller with an array with the `img` urls, and a function that returns a random one of these urls:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var images = [
        'http://placehold.it/200x200', 
        'http://placekitten.com/200/300', 
        'http://www.lorempixum.com/400/300'
    ];

    $scope.getRandomImage = function () {
        var randIndex = ~~(Math.random() * images.length);
        return images[randIndex];
    };
}
```

This is used in an expression in the html:

```
<img ng-src="{{getRandomImage()}}">
```

Here the Angular directive ng-src is used, because it's not allowed to have angular expressions in a src attribute.

Might be a bit overkill to use angular though.